# SQLCLR: Run 32 bit .Net dll in 64 bit SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dll, 64-bit

I have a 32 bit dll which is called from a stored procedure. It works fine with 32 bit sql server but now when i call that procedure from 64 bit sql server 2005 developer edition it gives an exception.

**How can I make a 32 bit dll to run from 64 bit sql server?**

Please note I do not have the source code for the dll, therefore recompiling won't be a option  .

Comment: Is it a vendor DLL?  If so, check with them to see if they have a 64bit version.  If its yours and you don't have the source code, you have some bigger problems on the way.

Comment: I heard something named SQL CLR might be a solution does anyone have an idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

64 bit SQL Server can only call 64 bit DLLs but there are some tweaks. I never tried.

I think [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/226709/32-bit-dll-on-sql-server-2008-x64) might help you.

Or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlservermigration/thread/01370e7d-a427-4263-bf68-fefb15d02462)

Comment: #6 from the first post seems like a good fix: Find a 32 bit server, install the DLL there and call it from the 64 bit server via a Linked Server.

Comment: What about SQL CLR i read it somewhere that it could be a solution but dont know how any idea ?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried. [Here is an MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Create a vbscript/powershell script to call the COM component and call the script from within the stored procedure. and this one ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, here is what I did to overcome the problem.

You can not load 32 bit dll in SQL 64 bit using SQLCLR functions, it won't work. Still you can acheive using SQLCLR by following the below method.

Create 64 bit DLL which can write the passing parameters to the txt file from the SQL.

Create a Windows service in 32 bit, using filesystemwatcher, and in the _changed event get the txt file, read the content and call the method from the 32 bit dll.

I hope this will solve your problem.